# Set-AzureStaticVNetIP allocated IP address not persisting over VM de-allocation

Tags: domain-controller, azure, static-ip

I am experimenting with the Set-AzureStaticVNetIP powershell command to allocate a static IP address to VMs.  I can get the command to work and allocate an IP address correctly to a VM, either on creation or once it is running, but nothing I do will persuade the VMs to continue to use this allocated IP address once the machine has been stopped and deallocated in the Azure console .

Am I doing something wrong - or is my understanding of this command wrong ?  I thought it was designed specifically to allow a persistent IP to be allocated to domain controllers etc, as described in the azure documentation here

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-new-forest-virtual-machine/

To answer the question below - I am calling UpdateVm after making the change, if applied to a running VM.  This restarts the VM in question and it comes up correctly with the assigned IP address - the issue still remains that this IP address is not retained after a stop and de-allocate from the azure console.

Further update - it is the internal IP address which is changing, and I've tried calling Set-AzureStaticVNetIP both on create and update of VMS.

TIA

Matt

Comment: Are you executing Update-AzureVM after? Note: This will restart the VM.

Comment: Just to clarify (please edit your question): Are you seeing the *external* IP address changing, or the *internal* IP address changing? Also, please clarify whether you called `Set-AzureStaticVNetIP` when first creating the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - the command works as expected if everything is in the EastUS region, but not in the European regions.